# How to get github issues(tickets) from terminal?

Tags: github, github-api

There is a way to get all the issues from a git repository? I need to populate a mysql database with the issues of a specific project with the issues status, reporter, priority, etc... Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "git issue" or "git ticket." Are you referring to GitHub? http://developer.github.com/v3/issues

Comment: I'm referring to GitHub issues, but I want to know if there is a way to show them with a git command

Comment: For future reference, Git != Github

Comment: @erosespinola: Git repository contains no information about issue tracker hosted within GitHub. Version control system is unaware of your task management system. The only way to achieve that would be through hacking (like extending Git with something rolled by you). So, simplifying: you cannot get GitHub issues using `git` command line tool. But you can use GitHub API in (almost) any way you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git and GitHub are two different things. The former is a version control system which does not know anything about “issues” or “tickets”, while the latter is a project platform with source hosting and issue management. So the GitHub issues are *very specific* to GitHub. No *Git* command will be able to give you GitHub issues.

There is [hub](http://defunkt.io/hub/) ([repository](https://github.com/defunkt/hub)), a wrapper around Git, which adds a few GitHub specific functionalities, like interacting with pull requests from the command line. For all browsing-related tasks it refers to the web browser though. And that’s also GitHub’s primary interface.

There does exist an [API for issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) though, so you could utilize that. There is [ghi](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi) which utilizes the API and does offer you access to GitHub issues from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`ghi`](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi), here's what it does:

> By default, ghi looks for GitHub issues by resolving the current
>   working directory's repository: first it looks for an `upstream` remote,
>   then it looks at `origin`.

Gives you a nice list of issues, a detail view, close/edit/assign features etc. I'm never leaving the terminal again.

Answer (score 1):

Github provides a web api for their ticket system. It is documented [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) and you can write a small program to fetch them and look through them.