# how to backup issues/tickets from github?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to backup issues/tickets from github ? I did see [How to get github issues(tickets) from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092863/how-to-get-github-issuestickets-from-terminal) but that doesn't answer my question. I want the ability to backup rather than just fetching it using ghi, although that is a good tool too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching you can set up a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). A webhook will deliver a JSON payload based off of an event.  For example, by using the [`IssueEvent`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuesevent) webhook you can send a JSON blob of every new issue's data to wherever you'd like to store your backup of these issues. If desired, you could also use the [`IssueCommentEvent`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuecommentevent) webhook to also collect the comments made on an issue.